# Dual space of measurable functions

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Denote $L^0$ the space of measurable functions with respect to a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

$d(X,Y)=E[\min(|X-Y|,1)]$ is a metric on $L^0$ and its convergence is equivalent to convergence in probability.

Moreover $d$ induces a topology, such that $(L^0,d)$ is a topological vector space.

Now I want to show following properties of its dual space:

1.) If $f\in (L^0)'$, then there exists a $\delta>0$, such that for any $C\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(C)\le \delta$, it holds $f(1_C)=0$.

2.) $(L^0)'=\{0\}$, if for every $C\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\delta>0$ with $0\le\delta\le P(C)$, there exists a measurable $D\subseteq C$, such that $P(D)=\delta$.

In 1.) I can see that $P(C)\le\delta$ is familiar with the notion of convergence in probability. Also I can image, that $f(1_C)=0$ means some sort of orthogonality, but I do not succeed with any tries. I really would appreciate some help on those. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $P(C_n)\to 0$ then $\sum_n a_n 1_{C_n}$ converges for $d$ independently of the growth of $(a_n)$. The continuity of $f$ means that $\sum_n a_n f(1_{C_n})$ converges. This implies 1) directly.

Comment: How do you show the convergence of $\sum_n a_n 1_{C_n}$ ?

Comment: For $|a_n| > 1$, $d(0,a_n 1_{C_n})=P(C_n)$ (I should have said the $C_n$ are disjoint or $\sum_n P(C_n)<\infty$ but it shouldn't change much the argument)

Comment: I see, that $d(0,\alpha\cdot1_{C_n})\rightarrow 0$, then also that $d(0,\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\cdot1_{C_i})\rightarrow 0$, but how do you find it for the sum $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: In a complete metric space if $\sum_n d(0,x_n)$ converges then so does $\sum_n x_n$

Comment: Yes, but actually I am still wondering why this space should be complete. I feel embarrassed :-(

Comment: $f$ is continuous : it is a functional on the completion

Comment: @user408858: $(L_0,d)$ is a complete metric space (once identification of a.s equal functions). If $(X_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L_0,d)$, then for any $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$, the is $n_\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\sup_{m,k\geq n_\ell} P[|X_k-X_m|>2^{-\ell}]<2^{-\ell}
$$
Hence $\sum_\ell P[|X_{n_{\ell+1}}-X_{n_\ell}|>2^{-\ell}]<\infty$, and by Borel-Cantelli's, for $P$ a.a $\omega\in\Omega$, there is $L_\omega\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|X_{n_{\ell+1}}(\omega)-X_{n_\ell}(\omega)|\leq 2^{-\ell}$ whenever $\ell\geq L$. Therefore $X=\lim_{\ell}X_{n_\ell}$ exists $P$ a.s. and so in $L_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuity of $f$ at $0$ implies that there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(X)|\le 1$ for all $X\in L^0$ with $d(X,0)\le \delta$. For $P(C)\le \delta$ you get, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, that $$d(nI_C,0) =E[\min(nI_C,1)]=E[I_C]\le \delta$$ and thus $|f(I_C)|\le 1/n$. This implies $f(I_C)=0$.

For the second part, you can use the assumtion to decompose any measurable set $D$ into two disjoint parts $D=D_1\cup D_2$ with $P(D_j)=P(D)/2$. Repating this with $D_j$ you get a disjoint decomposition $D=C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_n$ with $P(C_j)\le \delta$. Linearity of $f$ and the first part then imply $f(I_D)=0$. Again by linearity you get $f(X)=0$ for all simple function (linear combinations of indicator functions), by monotone approximation for all positive $X$ and by decomposing $X$ into ist positive and negative part, for all $X\in L^0$.